# how to get parent element class list in java script

Tags: javascript

I am using angular for our application.
how to get the parent element of  tag.

```
<button _ngcontent-ulk-c11="" class="btn cust-btn blm-cust-btn active" type="button" ng-reflect-klass="btn cust-btn blm-cust-btn" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]"><i _ngcontent-ulk-c11="" class="blm-icon-grid"></i></button>
```

I have tried below but not working.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("blm-icon-grid").parentElement
```

Comment: right way is document.getElementsByClassName("blm-icon-grid")[0]

Comment: thanks bro it is working

Answer (score 0):

Right way to use `getElementsByClassName()` is passing position:

```
 document.getElementsByClassName("blm-icon-grid")[0]
```

Comment: FYI it is not an array.

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript**

```
document.getElementsByClassName("blm-icon-grid")[0].parentElement
```

**JQuery**

```
$(".blm-icon-grid")[0].parentElement
```